# need to send xml format in the mail

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, xml, web-services

I'm trying to send mail.In the body section when i used html format it render as it is .Actually that is stored in an xml file so how could i send that xml format so that when somebody recieve the mail it will visible in proper format.

webservice code

```
  public Thankyou()
    {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 

        MailMessage o = new MailMessage("esh_p07@hotmail.com", "esh07@gmail.com", "Event Inquiry", @"< html >
< head >< title >[#text:@@hotelname#] Event Inquiry Form</title></head>
< body >
< h1 style = ""font - family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans - serif; font - weight:normal; font - size:14px; "" > You have received an email via the < b >[Culver Hotel </ b > Event Inquiry form.</ h1 >
          < h2 style = ""font - family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans - serif; font - weight:normal; font - size:12px; "" >
                    < b > From: </ b >[#text:contact_name#] <a href=""mailto:[#text:contact_email#]"" >[#text:contact_email#]</a><br>
< b > Phone: </ b > [#text:contact_phone#]<br>
< b > Requested Date: </ b > [#text:rfp_requestmonth#] [#text:rfp_requestdate#],[#text:rfp_requestyear#]<br>
< b > Requested Time: </ b > [#text:requested_time#]<br>
< b > Number of Guests: </ b > [#text:number_guests#]<br>
< b > Comments: </ b >< br > [#text:contact_comments#]
</ h2 >
                      </ body >
                      </ html >");
        NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential("user@example.com", "pAssw0rd");
        SmtpClient smtpobj = new SmtpClient("wm.ebservices.com", 38);
        smtpobj.EnableSsl = false;
        smtpobj.Credentials = netCred;
        smtpobj.Send(o);


    }
```

This is the body format which is stored in xml format i want that when somebody recieve the mail it will be visible in proper format currrently i'm geeting message with html tag also

xml code

```
<html>
<head><title>[#text:@@hotelname#] Event Inquiry Form</title></head>
<body>
<h1 style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:normal; font-size:14px;">You have received an email via the <b>[Culver Hotel</b> Event Inquiry form.</h1>
<h2 style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:normal; font-size:12px;">
<b>From: </b>[#text:contact_name#] <a href="mailto:[#text:contact_email#]" >[#text:contact_email#]</a><br>
<b>Phone: </b> [#text:contact_phone#]<br>
<b>Requested Date: </b> [#text:rfp_requestmonth#] [#text:rfp_requestdate#],[#text:rfp_requestyear#]<br>
<b>Requested Time: </b> [#text:requested_time#]<br>
<b>Number of Guests: </b> [#text:number_guests#]<br>
<b>Comments: </b><br> [#text:contact_comments#]
</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you actually mean XML or are you really saying XHTML (or HTML 5 plus XML which is sometimes referred to as XHTML5)? Either way, you probably don't want to send it as the boy of an email, you should extract the data from the form to build the email and send that.

Comment: actually in this application the data which is stored is send in format as i shown in xml part but it render with all html tag in the mail which i don't want, how to achieve that

Comment: Try the other response it may do what you want. I don't generally work with SOAP, so I can't be certain if its right. Also, I've edited this Q and your other one to remove something you don't want in there. I expect those edits to be approved shortly.

Comment: You may have special characters that need encoding.  Use System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode() and/or System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode();  See wiki : https://www.google.com/search?q=wiki+xml+html+characters&rlz=1C1OPRA_enUS563US647&oq=wiki+xml+html+characters&aqs=chrome.0.69i59.8744j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to create the xml using web-Services with the data you provided. You will need to create interface using SOAP bindings either RPC or document. Then add the implementation of the interface.
Make sure you add and render your java classes with **@WebSerive** and **@SOAPBinding** annotations.
Than ,your implementation class should override the method which adds the following data as an object of another class or indivisual variables. :

```
<b>From: </b>[#text:contact_name#] <a href="mailto:[#text:contact_email#]" >[#text:contact_email#]</a><br>
<b>Phone: </b> [#text:contact_phone#]<br>
<b>Requested Date: </b> [#text:rfp_requestmonth#] [#text:rfp_requestdate#],[#text:rfp_requestyear#]<br>
<b>Requested Time: </b> [#text:requested_time#]<br>
<b>Number of Guests: </b> [#text:number_guests#]<br>
<b>Comments: </b><br> [#text:contact_comments#]
```

After that you need to create a publish class and publish your webserice. Hit the url you will mention in the publish class and you will get the xml format your data.

Then you can get the xml file from url and mail it as you have done. Cheers !!!

Comment: sahil i dont want to  xml i just want the data which i m sending in body section will appear in mail without any <html> tag since it is rendering with tag now in mail

Comment: i guess if u want to send the mail as a message variable which is in html format than you should use javascript to first get the data inside the tags and save those variables into another message variable and then mail it.
To get the data inside the tags of your html document ,you can use :
`var variable = document.createElement("DIV");
 variable.innerHTML = b;
and then return :  variable.textContent || variable.innerText || "";`

Comment: sahil i got your point but not able to completely implement could you suggest more.

Comment: If it's not the answer you want or need, why did you accept the answer?